# TDS Package Bundling does not work with NuGet Package Generation

Tags: helix, tds, visual-studio, nuget, dependency-management

I am attempting to separate and version the Helix Foundation Layer modules into its own solution.  I am using TDS/VS2017/Sitecore_8.1U2.
Based on documentation, I would like to generate an Update package which I am able to bundle all Foundation modules by using the "Multi-project Properties" --> Package Bundling option.  This works well and allows me to deploy into Sitecore target environment.

However, for developers that need to take Foundation Layer as a dependency, I am trying to figure out how to enable VS2017 development.  When I attempt to generate NuGet package equivalent of the Update package, the bundling option does not take effect.  TDS NuGet Package only includes items that are compiled to outputpath of that particular project.

I wonder what do other folks do to enable multi solution development into a same Sitecore instance.  How do folks manage item/code depedencies that need to be present in the VS2017 but not deployed with that solution (usually encompassing feature or project layer modules).